# uptodate used adjectively or as a preposition

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

In the following sentence

> With a view to an amicable settlement, we offer you without prejudice Rs 10000 in full settlement of your claims **uptodate**

I looked up the meaning of the word **uptodate** and everywhere I found it to be an adjective but I think in the above sentence it is used as a preposition.

But if it is a preposition it must be written as up to date

Am I right?

Comment: "Up to date" is wrong: it should be "to date", which is a preposition phrase modifying "claims".

Answer (score 1):

"Up" is a preposition, and "to" is a preposition.

But "up-to-date" is indeed an adjective. My dictionary lists it, as Gustavson says, with hyphens. However I don't think his suggestion for the adverbial "up to date" is very common.

The more usual word I have heard in American use for the phrase you want is "**to date**": "... in full settlement of your claims **to date**." Perhaps this is a U.S. variant, but that's the expression I hear most often.

By the way, there is also a related verb: "to **update**" (one word).

Comment: What is the meaning of up-to-date claims?, Does it mean modern claims?

Comment: "Up-to-date claims" would be like anything that was "up-to-date": the most current set of claims that exist at the present time.